# Visual 2010 MFC new project doesn't build!

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

I just created a new project in Visual 2010. It is a multi-document MFC (static link) application with the HTML help option, Visual Studio 2008 style (with style changing option), that's about it.

Just after creation, I hit Build Solution and I get a lot build errors all in afxcomctl32.h. Errors like:

Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPCWS'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxcomctl32.h 426 1

On this line:
AFX_ISOLATIONAWARE_STATICLINK_FUNC(HWND ,CreateWindowExW,(DWORD dwExStyle,LPCWS TR lpClassName,LPCWSTR lpWindowName,DWORD dwStyle,int X,int Y,int nWidth,int nHeight,HWND hWndParent,HMENU hMenu,HINSTANCE hInstance,LPVOID lpParam),(dwExStyle,lpClassName,lpWindowName,dwStyle,X,Y,nWidth,nHeight,hWndParent,hMenu,hInstance,lpParam),NULL)

Same errors in Debug and Release.

My PC is Windows 7 Ultimate. What's the problem???
Best regards,
Downy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AFX_ISOLATIONAWARE_STATICLINK_FUNC(..., LPCWS TR lpClassName, ...)
```

That code got messed up, there is a space or tab inserted in LPCWSTR.  Deleting it will fix the problem.

However, that changed the timestamp on the file as well, you may run into trouble when you install a future service pack.  One thing to try is to rename the file, then run a Repair to get the original file back.  Or copy it off another machine.

Comment: ha!
I was so sure it was something missing (.h or something from the installation) that I didn't see what you suggested!!

It was it, thanks a lot. I have no clue why it got corrupted like this and I'll follow your advice and repair or find the original file on another machine.

Thanks again!
Downy